# passing $_POST to class constructor by default

Tags: php, class, constructor

For example, when using this code:

```
function __construct($args = '') {
```

it works fine if I instantiate the class with `$obj = new class_name($_POST)`, but when I use:

```
function __construct($args = $_POST) {
```

I get an unexpected T_VARIABLE error. Is there a particular reason why this doesn't work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't set a default parameter value to a variable

Comment: Of course you can set a default parameter. It just has to be a constant, not another variable. value....http://ideone.com/MkJ1W5

Comment: @Rottingham: not to the value of a variable, you can't.  That's what the previous comment was saying.

Comment: I suppose the reason for this is to avoid a fatal if the variable is not set when the class is constructed, or a variable scope issue, I was just hoping it may be possible since you can use dependency injection in a class constructor and assign that to an object.

Answer (score 4):

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

You could use something like this

```
function __construct(array $args = null) {
    if (is_null($args))
        $args = $_POST;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just trying to save myself from having to write an extra if condition, if it was possible to set it in the default.

Answer (score 0):

Better use it inside the constructor, $_POST can be accessed inside Objects.

Comment: True, it is a global after all. I was just trying to assign it to $args. No particular reason I suppose other than to save myself some keystrokes

Comment: I'd hazard to say that passing it to the object is better ANYWAY it allows you to test more easily, and swap out the arguments down the track if needed.